# Why fstream::tellg() return value is enlarged by the number of newlines in the input text file, when file is formated for Windows (\r\n)?

Tags: c++, windows, newline, fstream

Program openes input file and prints current reading/writing position several times.

If file is formated with '\n' for newline, values are as expected: 0, 1, 2, 3.

On the other side, if the newline is '\r\n' it appears that after some reading, current position returned by all tellg() calls are offsetted by the number of newlines in the file - output is: 0, 5, 6, 7.

All returned values are increased by 4, which is a number of newlines in example input file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::cout;
using std::setw;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    std::fstream ioff("su9.txt");
    if(!ioff) return -1;
    int c = 0;

    cout << setw(30) << std::left << " Before any operation " << ioff.tellg() << endl;

    c = ioff.get();
    cout << setw(30) << std::left << " After first 'get' " << ioff.tellg() << " Character read: " << (char)c << endl;

    c = ioff.get();
    cout << setw(30) << std::left << " After second 'get' " << ioff.tellg() << " Character read: " << (char)c << endl;

    c = ioff.get();
    cout << setw(30) << std::left << " Third 'get' " << ioff.tellg() << "\t\tCharacter read: " << (char)c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Input file is 5 lines long (has 4 newlines), with a content:

```
-------------------------------------------
abcd
efgh
ijkl


--------------------------------------------
```

output (\n):

```
Before any operation         0
After first 'get'            1      Character read: a
After second 'get'           2      Character read: b
Third 'get'                  3      Character read: c
```

output (\r\n):

```
Before any operation         0
After first 'get'            5      Character read: a
After second 'get'           6      Character read: b
Third 'get'                  7      Character read: c
```

Notice that character values are read corectly.

Answer (score 1):

The first, and most obvious question, is why do you expect any
particular values when teh results of `tellg` are converted to
an integral type.  The only defined use of the results of
`tellg` is as a later argument to `seekg`; they have no defined
numerical significance what so ever.

Having said that: in Unix and Windows implementations, they will
practically always correspond to the *byte* offset of the
physical position in the file.  Which means that they will have
some signification *if* the file is opened in binary mode; under
Windows, for example, text mode (the default) maps the two
character sequence 0x0D, 0x0A in the file to the single
character `'\n'`, and treats the single character 0x1A as if it
had encountered end of file.  (Binary and text mode are
indentical under Unix, so things often seem to work there even
when they aren't guaranteed.)

I might add that I cannot reproduce your results with MSC++.
Not that that means anything; as I said, the only requirements
for `tellg` is that the returned value can be used in a `seekg` to
return to the same place.  (Another issue might be how you
created the files.  Might one of them start with a UTF-8
encoding of a BOM, for example, and the other not?)

Comment: MinGW gcc 4.8.1-4 was used. Input file created in Notepad++. Question is actually related to example from "C++ Primer; 5 ed.; S. B. Lippman, Josee Lajoie, B. E. Moo" chapter 17.5 "The IO Library Revisited". Example is different than above, but it also gives uncorect (different than description in text suggests) result.